# pandas dataframe - add to woocommerce via REST API

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, woocommerce

I have a script with code like that:

```
scraped = {
            'Name *': title,
            'Price': price,
            'Image URLs': images,
        }

        scrapedresult.append(scraped)
        df = pd.DataFrame(scrapedresult)
        print(df)
        df.to_csv('1.csv')
```

Instead of writing the df to a csv file, i want to directly upload the product to woocommerce. How do i accomplish that in python?

Comment: Have a look at this package: [https://pypi.org/project/WooCommerce/](https://pypi.org/project/WooCommerce/)

Comment: i tried: https://pastebin.com/s8RbgAVk but it doesnt import anything

Comment: i think the WooCommerce api wants a dictionary not a dataframe

Comment: can i convert the df to a dictionary?

Comment: i try it now this way: https://pastebin.com/Zg2GDMKu still not working

Comment: what response are you getting from the endpoint?

Comment: looks like the api is expecting lowercase names. so not "Name" but "name"

Comment: try this tutorial: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-work-with-the-woocommerce-rest-api-with-python

Comment: yes, i wrote the names small but now nothing gets created instead of a blank product. the column names i used as in the tut

Comment: what response are you getting from the api?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238144/discussion-between-bendik-knapstad-and-mistert1984).